# PHP pegar valor de um array multidimensional

Tags: php, json, array, foreach

```
 $arquivo = '{"nome":"João","cpf":"00000","teste":"ooooo"}';
 $dd = json_decode($arquivo, TRUE);

foreach($dd as $value)
{
$nome = $value->{'nome'};
$cpf = $value->{'cpf'};

}
```

Eu quero pegar o valor de nome e cpf do array porém o resultado vem null para as variaveis, alguem sabe como resolver? por favor

Comment: Isso me parece mais um erro de sintaxe.

Comment: eu escrevo echo $value; , ai vem "João" , como se só tivesse esse valor lá

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você utiliza a função json_decode, ele converte os dados json em um array associativo, logo você pode utilizar o foreach chamando elemento de um vetor utilizando um índice e não atributos de um objeto. Por exemplo:

```
<?php
$arquivo = '[{"nome":"João","cpf":"00000","teste":"ooooo"},{"nome":"João 2","cpf":"000002","teste":"ooooo2"}]';
$dd = json_decode($arquivo, TRUE);
foreach($dd as $value){
    echo $value['nome'].'<br/>';
    echo $value['cpf'].'<br/>';
    echo $value['teste'].'<br/>';
}
?>
```

No exemplo acrescentei mais um elemento json, para que fique dois registros para lhe ajudar a entender.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!